# How to use CKEditor in a Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, ckeditor, jqmodal

If I use the [CKEditor](http://cksource.com/ckeditor) plugin in an HTML page based on a Bootstrap template, it works great, however if I insert the editor on a Bootstrap Modal like this

```
<!-- Modal --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAddBrand" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria labelledby="modalAddBrandLabel" aria-hidden="true">   
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalAddBrandLabel">Add brand</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
             <form>
             <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
             This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
             </textarea>            <script>
             CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
             </script>
             </form> 
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button id="AddBrandButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
       </div>
     </div>   
   </div> 
</div>
```

The editor works, but all the form controls on the popup windows of the editor are disabled, if you try to add a link or an image, for example, you cannot insert the URL or any description because the inputs are disabled.

Any workaround for this issue?

This is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/7zDay/

Comment: look this example http://jsfiddle.net/7zDay/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap with CKEditor equals problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420300/bootstrap-with-ckeditor-equals-problems)

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678662/ckeditor-issue-with-bootstrap-modal/31679096) gives a **better solution which works with more dialogs**.

Answer (score 56):

This should help http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/4PACy/

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
    var $modalElement = this.$element;
    $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
        var $parent = $(e.target.parentNode);
        if ($modalElement[0] !== e.target && !$modalElement.has(e.target).length
            // add whatever conditions you need here:
            &&
            !$parent.hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') && !$parent.hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
            $modalElement.focus()
        }
    })
};
```

**Update October 2016:**

CDN link for CKEditor has been changed, so I updated jsfiddle

Comment: Not even sure what this does but it fixes my problem! Hero.

Comment: Thumbs up for the solution but what is the reason behind not working>?

Comment: works!  just create a separate file and include it just after the jquery and bootstrap scripts. helped me to save my time and nerves!

Comment: this didnt work for me. for another generic solution check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678662/ckeditor-issue-with-bootstrap-modal

Comment: @gnarlyCharlie4 I fixed a jQuery version in the jsfiddle example. This solution works fine with jQuery versions 1.7.2 - 2.1.3 and it doesn't work with jQuery 3.0.0-alpha

Comment: Saved me! +1 Thanks!

Comment: THIS is the Solution what i've been keen on.
according to the @peterb mentioned link, after including jquery and bootstrap, put this code and works fine :)

Comment: Wow, this is the only solution I've found after searching for an hour that works. Thanks!

Comment: Any solution for ckeditor in material-ui  dialog in react...?

Comment: or solution in only javascript

Comment: what an obsolete system we use. you saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

This is late to answer but doing css trick will solve the issue.

Default `z-index` of Bootstrap modal is `10051` and default `z-index` of ckeditor dialog are `10010`. The trick is just to increase ckeditor dialog z-index as below. put below code in your css file:

```
.cke_dialog
{
    z-index: 10055 !important;
}
```

Comment: For me not enough. I neede to change Z-index for .cke_dialog and .cke_dialog_background_cover too

Answer (score 3):

See the response from aaronsnow to this thread on the ckeditor forum:
http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Issue-with-Twitter-Bootstrap

He's given the code. Just put the code in js file and make sure you include the file after the jquery and bootstrap

Comment: // fix ckeditor/bootstrap compatiability bug when ckeditor appears in a bootstrap modal dialog
// Include this file AFTER both jQuery and bootstrap are loaded.

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
  modal_this = this
  $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
    if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length 
    && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') 
    && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
      modal_this.$element.focus()
    }
  })
};

Answer (score 3):

Use the 100% working script..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Include this file AFTER both jQuery and bootstrap are loaded.
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
      modal_this = this
      $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
        if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length 
        && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') 
        && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea')
        && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
          modal_this.$element.focus()
        }
      })
    };
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
  $(document).on({'show.bs.modal': function () {
                 $(this).removeAttr('tabindex');
      } }, '.modal');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just open **/core/config.js** in ckeditor files than change "**baseFloatZIndex**" variable

```
baseFloatZIndex = 10000
```

to

```
baseFloatZIndex = 20000
```

It will change the start "**z-index**" of your editor box and the **popups**.

Answer (score 2):

I just remove the tabindex="-1" from the dialog main div element. Here is the sample code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

I just remove this

```
tabindex="-1"
```

and it starts working.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined`

So I just replaced the `$` inside the script provided by `@Pavel Kovalev` above to `jQuery`.

```
jQuery.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
    modal_this = this
    jQuery(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
        if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length
                && !jQuery(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select')
                && !jQuery(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
            modal_this.$element.focus()
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to set the .cke_dialog_container z-index which is linked to your dialog container

```
.cke_dialog_container 
{
    z-index: 20000
}
```

and for the modal I have used something like given in an already answered post:

```
$("#createLot").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('tabindex');
    })
```

This solved my problem of dialog box on link click.

Comment: this is the correct answer we can remove the tabindex from html no need to do it with jquery but good catch

Answer (score 1):

In case someone encounters this issue I solved it by removing `tabindex="-1"` from the bootstrap modal tag.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, maybe in my version it's already fixed, but my solution is:

```
    $("#messageModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
     CKEDITOR.replace('message', {
       height: '400px',
       width: '100%'
     });
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

All very simple:

```
$('#modal').removeAttr('tabindex');

$('#modal').focusout(function(){
    $(this).css({'position':'relative'});
});

$('#modal').focusin(function(){
    $(this).css({'position':'fixed'});
});
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: $('#message-modal').removeAttr('tabindex');

    $('#message-modal').focusout(function(){
        if($('.cke_dialog_background_cover').css('display')=='block'){
            $(this).css({'position':'relative'});
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#message-modal').css({'position':'fixed'});
            },10);
        }
    });

Comment: this for CKEditor in modal

Comment: TabIndex prevents focus fields. everything else css positions

Answer (score 0):

This is very short and simple. import CKEditor Javascript config files from the path they are store in your app. This is mine

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>
```

After this you can call CKEditor to replace your textarea by doing this

```js
CKEDITOR.replace('topic', {
          uiColor: '#9AB8F3',
       language: "en-us",
       toolbar: "Custom",
          height: "200",
          width: "400",
       skin: "moono",
       toolbar_Custom: [
        ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline"], 
        ["NumberedList", "BulletedList", "-", "Outdent", "Indent", "-", "JustifyLeft", "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyBlock"], 
        ["Link", "Unlink"]
       ],  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.3.4/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>


<!-- Modal --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAddBrand" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="user-box">
                    <h2>Create a new discussion</h2>
                    <form method="post" id="discussion_add" action="#">
                     <!--FORM FIELD START-->
                     <div class="form">
                         <div class="input-container">
                             <input type="text" id="id_session" name="session" required="true">
                         </div>
                         <div class="input-container">
                          <textarea cols="40" id="id_topic" name="topic" rows="10"></textarea>
                         </div>

                         <div class="input-container">
                             <button class="btn-style">Create Discussion</button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </form>                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddBrand">Launch Modal</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found some solution for this.

As @Pavel Kovalev suggested it have something to do with boostraps 4 JS and focus in modal script. I had just same problem as Yours.

There is an option for modals called "focus" which sets focus on initialized modals. Disabling this option makes all Your inputs in CKEditors modals work as they should. Not having focus on this modal i can live without :)

See details here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#options

In my approach to this i finaly got something like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" data-focus="false" id="newsAdd" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fieldAdd" aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
```

Also it is propably good idea for some more extensive testing, especialy if You have multiple bootstrap modals with CKEditor on one page.

As for the all the "fixes" You can propably find on web. Have a look that they most likely refer to bootstrap 3 where events on modal are different so they simply cannot work. Including @Pavel Kovalev solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with `bootstrap 4.4` and `ckeditor 4.14`. All you need to do is to initialize the ckeditor in your modal's `shown.bs.modal` event.

```js
$('#yourModal')
    .on('shown.bs.modal', (e) => {
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor')
});
```

worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4, this line will no longer work. They will need to figure out that it changed to:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {};
```

Instead of

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

So, Code should be like this:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus  = function() {
        modal_this = this
        $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
          if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length 
          && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') 
          && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
            modal_this.$element.focus()
          }
        })
      };
```

Comment: In my case $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus exists, but it is not called... Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

From the official ckeditor (v5) docs on using it with bootstrap (as of May 2023): https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/css.html#compatibility-with-bootstrap

The text, as links often become stale:

### Bootstrap modals

We noticed that Bootstrap modals cover the UI of the rich-text editor and break the input fields. Knowing that, you will need to take the following steps to get CKEditor 5 working in the Bootstrap environment:

Configure the z-index of the floating editor UI (e.g. balloons) so it is displayed over the Bootstrap overlay.
Configure Bootstrap so it stops “stealing” the focus from the rich-text editor input fields.
To address the first issue, add the following styles to your application:

```
/*
 * Configure the z-index of the editor UI, so when inside a Bootstrap
 * modal, it will be rendered over the modal.
 */
:root {
    --ck-z-default: 100;
    --ck-z-modal: calc( var(--ck-z-default) + 999 );
}
```

Pass the focus: false option to Bootstrap modal() function to fix the second issue:

```
$( '#modal-container' ).modal( {
    focus: false
} );
```

Check out the demo of CKEditor 5 rich-text editor working correctly with Bootstrap.

### Bootstrap table styles

There is also a known issue concerning table styles brought by Bootstrap breaking the table (widget) layout during editing. If you do not want any additional space around edited tables when using Bootstrap, add the following styles to your application:

```
/*
 * Override the width of the table set by Bootstrap content styles.
 * See: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/3253.
 */
.ck-content .table {
    width: auto;
}
```