# CKEditor issue with Bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I am having the same issue as pointed on [How to use CKEditor in a Bootstrap Modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637455/how-to-use-ckeditor-in-a-bootstrap-modal)

The problem however is that the fix doesnt seem to work any more.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAddBrand">Launch modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAddBrand" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAddBrandLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalAddBrandLabel">add</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            </form> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="AddBrandButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have put a fiddle (with the suugested fix added) on http://jsfiddle.net/7zDay/16/. Try using the math editor (using the sigma icon) and you would see that it does not let you type in the box.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the solution described in [this guide](https://gist.github.com/Reinmar/b9df3f30a05786511a42#ckeditor-inside-bootstrap-modals):

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
    $( document )
        .off( 'focusin.bs.modal' ) // guard against infinite focus loop
        .on( 'focusin.bs.modal', $.proxy( function( e ) {
            if (
                this.$element[ 0 ] !== e.target && !this.$element.has( e.target ).length
                // CKEditor compatibility fix start.
                && !$( e.target ).closest( '.cke_dialog, .cke' ).length
                // CKEditor compatibility fix end.
            ) {
                this.$element.trigger( 'focus' );
            }
        }, this ) );
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7zDay/17/. Works fine for me. AFAICS this is a more general fix.

Comment: WFM in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This is what I [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiG04.png) on Mac with Chrome and Safari. Do you see the toolbar in the jsFiddle?

Comment: Works really nice!!

Comment: This didn't work for me. My Link Popup for CKEditor comes up just behind the main source modal dialog. It could be a z-index or something

Comment: after wasting 7 hours i found this as working , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For whoever found the accepted solution not working, just add this CSS class:

```
.ck {z-index: 9999 !important;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
It's so simple and doesn't create any script conflict.    
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <title>Classic editor with default styles</title>
        <script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" >&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="http://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
        </textarea>

        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                height: 260,
                width: 700,
            } );
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: The question involved bootstrap modals, which is not addressed here.