# CKEditor + Bootstrap modal + LayoutManager plugin, selection.getStartElement() returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, ckeditor

Clicking on a bunch of buttons of my app allows to create different customized instances of CKEditor, furhermore inside the textarerea is created a grid whith layoutmanager plugin. The created editor is resides inside the body of a bootstrap modal.

When one of the buttons is clicked for the first time everything works fine, and i can get the correct start element and the editable area can be accassed properly from my app.
When i dispose the modal i destroy also the instance of CKEditor and  the associated view (the app involves also Backbone.js) is removed:

```
$('#tallModal').one('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
                if (this.ckeditor) {
                    CKEDITOR.instances[this.model.get("uniqueId")].destroy();
                    this.ckeditor = null;
                    }
                this.view.close();
            }.bind(this)).modal('hide');
```

`this.ckeditor` is created as follows:

```
this.ckeditor = $("#"+ this.model.get("uniqueId")).ckeditor(config.rte.ckeditor, $deferred.resolve).editor;
```

When i click another button the modal displays the correct editor instance but when this line in my code is reached (`this._editor` is an alias of `this.ckeditor`):

```
return this._editor.getSelection().getStartElement();
```

the following error is raised:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStartElement' of null
```

Debugging the code i discovered that when the editor is destroyed and then created again the editor object(`this._editor`) has the property `status="destroyed"`, while when everything is working properly `status="ready"`

I tried this solution [CKEditor issue with Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678662/ckeditor-issue-with-bootstrap-modal) and many others with no luck, the line `this.$element.trigger( 'focus' );` is called anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself an answer:

```
this._editor = CKEDITOR.instances[this.model.get("uniqueId")];
```

I had this line inside the `initialize` method of a `Backbone.View` but in this way i only get the reference to the destroyed instance.

The editor instance inside `this._editor` must be "refreshed" each time i want to do something with the result of:

```
 return this._editor.getSelection().getStartElement();
```