# CKEditor in a bootstrap Modal

Tags: ckeditor, bootstrap-modal

I read many solutions about this [How to use CKEditor in a Bootstrap Modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637455/how-to-use-ckeditor-in-a-bootstrap-modal) and neither of them work for me. I feel desperate... [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Eelke_Johnson/abucpue5/) <- the code Im curently using:

- JQuery 3.1.1
- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- Ckeditor 4.6.2

My html head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

My modal:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Launch modal</button>    
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="text" class="col-lg-2 control-label">CKeditor:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control"  name="text" rows="8" maxlength="400" minlength="20" required></textarea>
                </div>    
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</span></a>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My ckeditor script:

```
window.onload = function() {
          CKEDITOR.replace('text');
      };
```

The editor works, but all the form controls on the popup windows of the editor are disabled, if you try to add a link or an image, for example, you cannot insert the URL or any description because the inputs are disabled. If I use keyboard shortcuts it work but this is the buttons who're causing issue. Always the same error:

```
Unable to get property 'specified' of undefined or null reference ckeditor.js (100,288)
```

Any workaround for this issue?
[image of the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhwLq.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IN TAG HEAD

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

IN TAG BODY

```
<!-- HTML -->

<input type="button" id="btnModal" value="Open Modal" />

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text" class="col-lg-2 control-label">CKeditor:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">


                <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>


            </div>    
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</a>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

IN JQUERY

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnModal', function(){
    $('#modal').modal('show');
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
});
```

DEMO : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rwknrgx/)

Comment: Hi, first thank you for your answer. I used your code in my local server and still no change... CKEditor is working with windows.onload() and $(document).ready() but the button arn't working in any case. I tried your js fiddle who's working and I tried to put my code which is above in js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Eelke_Johnson/abucpue5/ here and it work also! But still, in my local server wamp this isnt working unfortunately.

Comment: in local , change src js ckeditor . change to  `https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js`

Comment: All sources are working correctly it dont seems to be that because nothing changes. When I load it, I have the same result I posted on the image. If I use keyboard shortcut it work (like ctrl+B for bold) but this is the command buttons who're making troubles.