# CKEditor Link input not working in modal

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, ckeditor, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I've got a project in which I use a modal with a form and a ckeditor and the Link input doesn't work.

Here's a fiddle that recreates this problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/8t882a2s/3/

And the code of this example.

HTML:

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" contenteditable="true" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bodyModal" contenteditable="true" class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn  margin-right-button-nav" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span> Edit Modal</button>
```

JS:

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        CKEDITOR.inline('myModalLabel');
        CKEDITOR.inline('bodyModal');
    })    
});
```

This isn't exactly my code but the bug is the same. If you click in the modal and then try do add a Link you can't write the url in the input field.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

lots of answers around the internet suggested multiple ways for fixes,
this worked for me, for a bootstrap 4 project:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {
                var $modalElement = this.$element;
                $(document).on('focusin.modal',function(e) {
                    if ($modalElement.length > 0 && $modalElement[0] !== e.target
                        && !$modalElement.has(e.target).length
                        && $(e.target).parentsUntil('*[role="dialog"]').length === 0) {
                        $modalElement.focus();
                    }
                });
            };
```

if your running on bootstrap 3, then override `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus` insdead.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer... worked for me ( bootstrap 3 ) ...Thanks !

Comment: I agree, this should be the accepted answer. This fixed the same problem that I was having with two separate HTML editors and their own dialog modals inside a Bootstrap modal!

Comment: For me, the empty function intialisation did the trick : $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function() {}

Comment: @ChenL thanks buddy, this works for me in bootstrap 4.

Comment: Agreed - Works in BS 4.5

Answer (score 7):

To solve this issue is enough to do the following things:

1. Add custom css rules on your body tag

   `body {
           --ck-z-default: 100;
           --ck-z-modal: calc( var(--ck-z-default) + 999 );
       }`
2. Set your modal options focus value to false

   - if you are using javascript to launch modal you should do it like this:

   `$( '#basicModal' ).modal( {
       focus: false
   } );`

   - if you are using data attributes to launch modal you should have it like this 
     `<div class="modal fade " data-focus="false" id="basicModal">`

Comment: In my case, the pop up window of link form was hiding behind the modal, and your css brought it back. Thank you

Comment: In Bootstrap 5, all I needed to do is add `data-bs-focus="false"` to the html. The css part was not needed.

Answer (score 2):

For me, removing `tabindex="-1"` from the modal attribute solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's right! For me data-focus="false" solved all issues