# Ckeditor4 textboxs not working in bootstrap modal?

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I am using `enter code here`ckeditor4 and `bootstrap5`,The editor opens in a modal form,The editor works well, but when I click on one of the options, for example, the link, and the page opens, its pods do not work and it is not possible to enter a value.

I searched a lot on the web, but my problem was not solved!!! I even deleted `tabindex`, but the problem was still not solved. Thank you for your help?

[image: Image Ckeditor Link]

I tried the following links, but the problem was not solved!!!

[CKEditor Link input not working in modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121577/ckeditor-link-input-not-working-in-modal)

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to the html modal and it worked

```
data-bs-focus="false"
```